# Odd ding sound when I'm typing sometimes?

Tags: macos, keyboard

In the past couple of weeks, I've noticed that while typing I will get a "ding" sound as if I am being notified of something. It will be a single ding. I'm not sure what's doing it, but it only happens when I type; I'm unable to reproduce it at will.

It is not *any* of the sounds in the Sounds effect tab of System Preferences.

I'm on iMac M1 running Monterey 12.5.1 and use an external keyboard.

Is there a way that I can find or track down what is causing this "ding?"

Here is the [audio of the ding](https://sndup.net/kgft/).

And here's a screenshot of Activity Monitor, ordered by CPU, at approximately the time of the ding:

[image: Screenshot of Activity Monitor, ordered by CPU]

Comment: Welcome.  Sorry that your first experience here is a downvote with no comment.  Allow me to assist... I've reworked your question so there is a practical problem to be solved, but it's still wanting in terms of details.  Is it possible to get an audio recording (just leave voice recording on until you capture it then load the snippit to a shared drive).  Also, when you hear it, try to stop and take a snapshot of Activity Monitor so we can see what's loaded at the approximate time the ding occurs.

Comment: I added the info you suggested, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It was coming from a piece of software called Typinator that I use. It turns out that it has sound options not just globally but for each set of typing corrections that it offers. I had to turn all the sounds off and I think it's problem solved.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!